# Add rule to allow ping to other subnet

Tags: mikrotik-routeros

I have two subnets on mikrotik address 192.168.5.1 (the network 192.168.5 and 192.168.6 ). What can I add to the firewall to be able to ping the network 192.168.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but here's my interpretation and answer:

You have two subnets, both connected to a Mikrotik router: `192.168.5.0/24` and `192.168.6.0/24`.

First, you need to give the Mikrotik router an address on both subnets. For example:

```
> /ip address
/ip address> add interface=ether2 address=192.168.5.1/24
/ip address> add interface=ether3 address=192.168.6.1/24
```

Now the Mikrotik router should be able to ping both subnets, and anything on one should be able to ping the other, assuming you don't have any filter rules specifically set up to deny it.